# "error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line" while compiling g13-driver

Tags: compiling, make

I'm trying to compile the download received here: `https://code.google.com/p/linux-g13-driver/` by running make but I'm receiving errors that to me, after searching on the web, look like they're the programmers fault but here they are:

```
g++ c-source/G13.o c-source/G13Action.o c-source/Macro.o c-source/MacroAction.o c-source/Main.o c-source/Output.o c-source/PassThroughAction.o -o Linux-G13-Driver  -lusb-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: c-source/Main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_kill@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Linux-G13-Driver] Error 1
```

If anyone has any ideas please help I really want to get this running

Comment: I found this [link](https://code.google.com/p/linux-g13-driver/issues/detail?id=13)

Comment: My first idea is that you should format the error text so that it is readable - each line of compiler output should be separated.  If you want someone to help, you need to do all you can to make it easier for them to do so.

Comment: I tried to i tabbed over eight spaces for each line and it did nothing

Comment: I got this error when `gcc -o cube cube.c -lglut -lGLU` for opengl.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit the lines as shown below in the makefile and it should compile:

```
FLAGS    = -L /lib64 
LIBS     = -lusb-1.0 -l pthread
```

Comment: unfortunately the driver won't install I guess cause it's 14.04.1 so it's kind of pointless but thanks anyway :P

Comment: Have you try to run as root, `sudo ./Linux-G13-Driver`

Comment: Ahh it does work!  It just says loading and then while it says loading you can use it, didn't realize that