# Compilation error of a macro

Tags: 14.04, compiling, keyboard-layout

I am new to Ubuntu and I am having real trouble with compiling g15macro-1.0.3 for my Logitech G110 keyboard. I can run

```
./configure
```

OK, but when I run make I get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/peter/G110/g15macro-1.0.3'
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -O3 -Wall -g -O2 -I. -I.  -g -O2 -avoid-version  -o g15macro g15macro.o  -lg15daemon_client -lg15render -lX11 -lXtst 
mkdir .libs
gcc -O3 -Wall -g -O2 -I. -I. -g -O2 -o g15macro g15macro.o  -lg15daemon_client -lg15render -lX11 -lXtst  
/usr/bin/ld: g15macro.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [g15macro] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/peter/G110/g15macro-1.0.3'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have upgraded GCC to 4.9.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you post the link where you found the code you're trying to compile? It looks like it's an issue with the code itself, but it's possible you missed some parameters at some point

Answer (score 0):

According to [this previously asked question about the G13](https://askubuntu.com/a/521717/452766):

"Edit the lines as shown below in the makefile and it should compile:

`FLAGS    = -L /lib64
 LIBS     = -lusb-1.0 -l pthread`"